# Solve compiling xamarin app -.MvvmCross - Missing reference mono.android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have just create a new project using single page MvvmCross cross template. When i  play  debug to compile project (android project is start project in my solution) i have this error (see attach). but i don't have a project json file in android project. Any advice is appreciated.

Error message:Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version=v81" framework.Add a reference to "monoAndroid, Version=v8.1" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run Nuget restore

[Compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGsg8.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add the error message to your question as text, rather than link to an external image.

Answer (score 0):

[first step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB5N7.png)

[second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCDCc.png)

[third step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQbOR.png)

So my steps to solve this problem have been:

1-Right click on my android project and select properties from context menù.
2-In application page (not manifest) i have changed destination framework version with the latest instead of the first voice (use more recent platform)